# Query to get a running total of an "inventory change" column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access that looks like this
[image: MS Access printscreen clip]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a 6th field that shows the sum of all changes up until that date.

I've achieved this easily in Excel by adding a SUM IF calculation, to illustrate what I need help with.
[image: MS Exccel Printscreen clip]

Now I need to remove Excel and have this done directly in Access.

Comment: You probably need `DSum` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a subquery for a running sum of Inventory:

Conditionally aggregate subquery

```
SELECT t1.[Date], t1.[Part SKU], t1.[SKU Name], t1.[SumOfInventory Change],
   (SELECT SUM(t2.[SumOfInventory Change]) 
     FROM [Inventory Report Table] t2
     WHERE t1.[Date] >= t2.[Date]
     AND t1.[Part SKU] = [t2.Part SKU]) AS [Inventory Level]
FROM [Inventory Report Table] t1
```

DSum() Subquery *(using dynamic criteria for date condition)*

```
SELECT t1.[Date], t1.[Part SKU], t1.[SKU Name], t1.[SumOfInventory Change],
   DSum("[SumOfInventory Change]", "[Inventory Report Table]", 
        "[Date] >=#" & t1.[Date] & "# AND [Part SKU] ='" & [t2.Part SKU] &"'") AS [Inventory Level]
FROM [Inventory Report Table] t1
```

If `[Date]` is stored as string and not date/time (from your post Access ACE/Jet does not by default store dates in that format which the other RDMS's do), replace `#` with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for providing two very elegant and better practice answers.

Comment: However, you missed that [Part SKU] = [Part SKU] too :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the user [Utsav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5234334/utsav) who made me aware of Dsum, I managed to make this DSum function, which solves my problem.

```
Expr1: DSum("[SumOfInventory Change]";
  "Inventory Report Table";
  "[Part SKU] = '" & [Part SKU] &
  "' AND Date Between #" & Format("2015-01-01";"mm/dd/yyyy") &
  "# And #" & Format([Date];"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
)
```

Comment: Very neat. If you can accept your own answer, it will put closure to this question. Thank you for sharing

Comment: But this gives you a YTD running sum. Was that your intention?

Comment: Yeah, for this year it's going to be YTD but next year it's going to be 2015-01-01 to date. Data starts at 2015-05-07 so the start date could just as well have been that or 1982-02-13 (my birthday) or whatever ;)